# Server error 500 en proyecto de laravel (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto de laravel que estoy instalando en una computadora con ubuntu 20.04 con mariaDB y Nginx, el problema es que cuando la instalo abro localhost o vía php artisan serve y me tira el error 500 sin información.
Ya intente cambiar los permisos a 755 y a 777 y sigue sin funcionar, me aparece la pantalla de inicio localhost, la pantalla localhost/login pero todo lo demás me tira el error 500.

Este es el log que me mando, lo agregó a drive porque es muy grande para poner aquí

[laravel.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vhNjucJusw7FpiElOagLctPyDqN1h43S/view?usp=sharing)

> [2020-10-22 20:46:33] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Log [] is not defined. at /var/www/html/controlescolar/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:192)
> [stacktrace]

Comment: Seguí el tutorial de esta web https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-laravel-7-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-nginx-and-mariadb pero lo aplique a mi proyecto.

Comment: Revisa los logs de laravel en `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: en ```.env``` revisa que tengas ```APP_DEBUG=true``` y veras el error que te esta dando

Comment: ¿No puedes colocar solo la parte inicial del log en lugar de mandarnos a un enlace externo?

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar esta parte del error 500 y a la vez un 403 not found que apareció después modificando el archivo 000-default.conf de apache, poniendo de manera correcta el directorio root dirigido a /var/www/html/nombredeproyecto/public
Además de eso los permisos para el proyecto en 755 y para la carpeta de storage en 777.

Comment: Seguro que es necesario dejar una carpeta de un servidor público con permisos 777? No será mejor definir correctamente el usuario o grupo con acceso a esos recursos?

Comment: Hola, si al final acabe haciendo eso en lugar de lo de arriba para no tener fallas en la seguridad, definí un usuario con acceso a esa base de datos y los permisos ya los coloque correctamente.